IDA detects a file as both a Windows and an MS-DOS program
Okay, I have one rather suspicious file that is even taking some control over my PC. However, I need it, so I decided to decompile it and see if it was harming my PC and can I cut it out?
I've used a couple of decompilers, but I'm currently using IDA 64 and it says that file possible has a few formats:pe64.dll, dos64.dll, binary file.
BTW it seems it has all this formats.
When I decompile it as MS-DOS EXE, I got this:

Possible packed file, continue? --> YES
The input file has extra information at the end (tail 22C53C0h, loaded 450h), continue? --> YES

Finlly I got only one function "start" at segment seg000 with this code inside
; Segment type: Pure code
seg000 segment byte public 'CODE' use16
assume cs:seg000
assume es:nothing, ss:seg000, ds:nothing, fs:nothing, gs:nothing


; Attributes: noreturn

public start
start proc near
push    cs
pop     ds
assume ds:seg000
mov     dx, 0Eh
mov     ah, 9
int     21h             ; DOS - PRINT STRING
                        ; DS:DX -> string terminated by "$"
mov     ax, 4C01h
int     21h             ; DOS - 2+ - QUIT WITH EXIT CODE (EXIT)
start endp              ; AL = exit code

When I decompile it as MS-DOS EXE, I got this:

Can't find translation for relative virtual address 0013C678, continue? --> YES

Now i got

65k of functions called sub_XXXXXXXXX,
Viev-A,
broken code,
export with only "start" (probably MS-DOS segment),
import with a sew libraries including InternetReadFile which is a litte bit suspicious as for me.


I believe this qualifies as "about software tools commonly used by programmers" and should not be closed. I voted that it belongs elsewhere (there's referseengineering.SE) but that's not reflected in the close reason.

Select "Portable executable" in the format selection dialog.
The fact is, for compatibility with DOS (when it was relevant), every PE executable has a DOS MZ executable header and a small thunk DOS program that prints smth like "This program cannot be run in DOS mode" and quits.
So every valid Windows executable is also a valid DOS executable -- thus IDA detects it as such.
Windows doesn't run this thunk program so even if the file contains malicious code, this is not where to look for it.

it's also possible to have fat DOS+Win32 binaries, i.e. the DOS part isn't just "This program cannot be run in DOS mode" but a full-fledged program if running in DOS. For example many zip self-extractors do that
